# sap.ui.layout.SplitPane Doesn't Apply SplitterLayoutData

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to set the size on `sap.ui.layout.SplitPane` on the left side as following:

```xml
<Page title="Where used">
  <l:ResponsiveSplitter defaultPane="default">
    <l:PaneContainer>
      <l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400">
        <l:layoutData>
          <l:SplitterLayoutData size="20%"/>
        </l:layoutData>
        <Panel height="100%">
          <Label text="Hello"/>
        </Panel>
      </l:SplitPane>
      <l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400">
        <Panel height="100%">
          <Label text="Hello"/>
        </Panel>
      </l:SplitPane>
    </l:PaneContainer>
  </l:ResponsiveSplitter>
</Page>
```

As you can see on the code, I tried to achieve with

```xml
<l:SplitterLayoutData size="20%"/>
```

But the size does not apply at all. What am I doing wrong?

I looked at this example: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.layout/test/sap/ui/layout/ResponsiveSplitter.html#L106, [[Result]](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/layout/ResponsiveSplitter.html)

Comment: Currently, it does matter in which order the aggregations are defined due to sequential evaluation of XML nodes and how SplitPane applies the layout data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52580994/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** The [fix](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/a404956296368f8c94ec7720877c959cdccb5f4b) should be available as of UI5 version 1.60. Otherwise, please keep reading..

---

Just figured out that it only works if the aggregation `<l:layoutData>` comes after the default aggregation.

```xml
<l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400">
  <Panel height="100%">
    <Label text="Panel 1"/>
  </Panel>
  <l:layoutData>
    <l:SplitterLayoutData size="20%"/>
  </l:layoutData>
</l:SplitPane>
```

.. which shouldn't actually matter. I'll analyse the source code why it matters and update the answer later.<sup>[1]</sup> But this is how you can "fix" it so that it works for now.

[image: responsive splitter]

Source: https://embed.plnkr.co/0yo35xOiSmF5eG6R?show=V.view.xml,preview

---

[1]: It turns out that SplitPane has an overwritten mutator for the `layoutData` aggregation:

> ```js
> SplitPane.prototype.setLayoutData = function(oLayoutdata) {
>   var oContent = this.getContent();
>   if (oContent) {
>     return oContent.setLayoutData(oLayoutdata);
>   } else {
>     return this;
>   }
> };
> ```
>
> [source](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/9a06292d7492d66e91531a02673dd813a2065b88/src/sap.ui.layout/src/sap/ui/layout/SplitPane.js#L59-L66)

As you can see, it applies the layout data not to itself but to its content. If the content doesn't exist at that moment, the `<layoutData>` is just ignored. And since XML nodes are evaluated [sequentially one by one](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/9a06292d7492d66e91531a02673dd813a2065b88/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/XMLTemplateProcessor.js#L121-L124), the `Panel` (content) had to come first before the `SplitterLayoutData`.

IMO this is clearly a bug in the framework since the framework has to assure that the outcome is always the same no matter in which order aggregations were defined (content <--> layoutData).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prabhatpathania/f9015rL6/)

```
oResponsiveSplitter = new sap.ui.layout.ResponsiveSplitter({
    defaultPane: "defaultPane",
    rootPaneContainer: [
        new sap.ui.layout.PaneContainer({
            orientation: "Horizontal",
            panes: [
                new sap.ui.layout.PaneContainer({
                    // orientation: "Horizontal",
                    panes: [
                        new sap.ui.layout.SplitPane({
                            demandPane: true,
                            content:  new sap.m.Panel({
                                headerText: "1",
                                content: new sap.m.Text({text: lorem + lorem})
                            }),
                            requiredParentWidth: 400
                        }),
                        new sap.ui.layout.SplitPane({
                            demandPane: false,
                            content:  new sap.m.Panel({
                                headerText: "2",
                                content: new sap.m.Text({text: lorem + lorem})
                            }),
                            requiredParentWidth: 400,
                            layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.SplitterLayoutData({
                                size: "20%"
                            })
                        }),
                        new sap.ui.layout.SplitPane({
                            demandPane: true,
                            content: new sap.m.Panel({
                                headerText: "3",
                                content: new sap.m.Text({text: lorem + lorem})
                            }),
                            requiredParentWidth: 400,
                        }),
                    ]
                })
            ]
        })
    ]
});
```

I think it answers your problem.

Also, I understand that here SplitterLayoutData size works as expected when the layout is horizontal.

Comment: It does not work, I created an example here http://next.plnkr.co/edit/8IGhIm5O22G01OMo?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview